# Why we use jquery.klass?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function something like this...

```
a.b.c.d = jQuery.klass({
    initialize: function(e, f, g, h) {}
});
```

Can anybody tell me why we use .klass?

Comment: You are looking for that plugin documentation, type on Google `jQuery klass Documentation`

Answer (score 0):

You can learn about jquery-klass-plugin from Following link:

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-klass-plugin/